# Creating curved line trajectory from linestring coordinates in Google Earth

Tags: google-earth, curve, spline

I have a set of coordinates with associated altitudes in Google Earth Pro. Is there any way to remove all of the sharp kinks created by the straight line joins and create a smooth, curved line that passes through the coordinates defined?

[image: Linestring coordinates]